# How do I know that mobile apps aren't stealing my login info?

Tags: mobile, audit, phishing

This thought just occurred to me. If you're using an unofficial client to access a service (ex. BaconReader for reddit), how can you be certain that your login information isn't being stolen?

Answer (score 4):

You can't, which is one of the big problems with password-based authentication for mobile apps.

Reddit also offers and strongly encourages use of OAuth. You can read more about OAuth elsewhere, but the summary is that each individual app gets its own token to use to authenticate to your account. This means you can revoke access for one app without needing to change your password for the website or other apps. In many OAuth implementations, you can specify a restricted set of permissions for each token as well, so you can limit the app from doing things other than what you expect it to.

However, many reddit apps have implemented the OAuth flow in a way that still allows them to sniff your password. The flow involves sending the user to reddit.com, where they authorize the app and are redirected back to the app. The least disruptive way to do this is to use a webview inside the app, **but** then the user is still entering their password into the app!

Comment: Agreed. Furthermore, you don't even know for sure that the traffic that app is generating is even encrypted in the first place. Credit Karma was caught a few years ago transmitting credit reporting data to/from their app in cleartext! Unlike web browsers, you don't get to see whether/what type of encryption is being used, view certificates, or anything, and development is usually delegated to cheap dev farms or interns just because companies feel compelled to have an app. Nothing good can come from this degree of abstraction-- always use the respective website where security is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t. If you are using an unofficial 3rd party app, and you have no way to trust it then you can’t be **certain** that your login information isn't being stolen.